# Programming a Discord bot in Python- Any tips to avoid exceeding the rate limit?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am working on a Discord bot, and got this error:

```
discord.errors.HTTPException: 429 Too Many Requests (error code: 0): You are being blocked from accessing our API temporarily due to exceeding our rate limits frequently. Please read our docs at https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits to prevent this moving forward.
```

Quite obviously, my bot is trying to do too much at once. I am not sure what measures to take that will help avoid this in the future, are there any suggestions/tips? How do the big-league bots like Dank Memer and carl-bot do so much without being rate-limited?

Comment: Try not to exploit your way around this because this can get you banned. You can only do 5 requests per every x amount of time tho

Answer (score 2):

The docs state that you receive the amount of requests you have left in the response headers:

https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits

```
X-RateLimit-Limit: 5
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 0
X-RateLimit-Reset: 1470173023
X-RateLimit-Bucket: abcd1234
```

At this point, assuming you are using a library like `requests`, you can access your response headers after each request like:

```
response = requests.get(your_url)
remaining_requests = response.headers.get('X-RateLimit-Remaining')
```

If `remaining requests == 0`, incorporate the value in your control flow and wait until the `X-RateLimit-Reset` epoch time to use the bot once again.

The API also tells you exactly how long you have to wait, so you can use that value right away:

```
< HTTP/1.1 429 TOO MANY REQUESTS
< Content-Type: application/json
< Retry-After: 65
< X-RateLimit-Limit: 10
< X-RateLimit-Remaining: 0
< X-RateLimit-Reset: 1470173023.123
< X-RateLimit-Reset-After: 64.57
< X-RateLimit-Bucket: abcd1234
{
  "message": "You are being rate limited.",
  "retry_after": 64.57, # <==== Use this value
  "global": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL shown in the error message leads to details of how to avoid the rate limits. You will need to implement code in your bot to stop calling the API when the API tells you you have no request remaining.